# Laravel 5.1 Custom Parameter on Custom Exception

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to create a custom exception with a custom parameter in it. I feel like I am doing something wrong here. Basically I would like to handle the exception in Laravel's exception handling file but I need extra data with the exception to know things like who caused the exception. This is what I have so far...

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class ApiException extends \Exception
{
    public $userId;

    public function __construct($userId, $message, $code, Exception $previous)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

}
```

The idea here was to pass the userId into the exception so I can access it later. But I am having a problem. In this case, I don't know what to pass in as the "$previous" variable...

```
throw new ApiException($user->id, 'im testing', 200, $previous);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php) on Exceptions

The previous variable is used for exception chaining and has a default value of `NULL`. You can add this to your extension.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class ApiException extends \Exception
{
    public $userId;

    public function __construct($userId, $message, $code, Exception $previous = NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

}
```

This way you can continue to support exception chaining, should you need it in the future, but not require it every time an ApiException is thrown.